# two same class divs side by side

Tags: css, html

How to make two divs with same class to float or appear in the same line side by side. The
problem is I can't add extra class/id. Those two divs have same default class which cannot be changed. I don't want to use javascript to add a new class/id. None of the answers whether on google or stack overflow or any where else show how to do it using same "class" If there is any other way to add class/id without using javascript than that would be appreciated too.

Comment: you can use float:left to your div class.

Comment: CSS selector could help you to sort those two div and use the class they already have, but no code , no guess , no chocolate :)

Comment: You can also use Inline-Block for the display style.

Comment: you need to post the html

Answer (score 2):

Two most common and simple ways are:

### 1. float: left

Example:

```css
.myDiv {
    float: left;
}
```

Divs will stick to each other if they both fit in the line. Disadvantage of this method is that the parent container will get confused so that further elements outside this parent may flow over it. In that case you'll have to use [clear-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best).

### 2. display: inline-block

Example:

```css
.myDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Very similar result to `float: left` but there might be small space between the divs, caused by *white-space*. [Here's more about this problem](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can add a `style` propery for an element, where you can assign `display:inline-block` or `float:left` or such. It all would look like this:

`<div class="divclass" id="div1" style="float:left"> asd </div>`

`<div class="divclass" id="div2" style="float:left"> asd </div>`

Comment: I understood he could not add or remove anything in HTML. he doesn't either say how many times in his document the class is used .

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/myc7N/1/

```
.myClass{
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
}
.someOtherClass{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: `clear:both` gives nothing here. You didn't add `content` and `display: block` property.

Comment: `clear:both` is resetting any floats which allows the next div to go back to being formatted properly on a new line. Check out the jsFiddle

Comment: No way, genius! Notice that `:after` is a _pseudo-element_ which **doesn't exist** without `content` property. The reason that third div in your fiddle stays in the new line is simple - there's no space for it since the first two are `50%` wide. Remove `clear: both` in your fiddle and you'll see NO change.

Comment: You're right, you'd have to clear on the next div on the DOM. I have updated my answer.